# Converting BlobColumn to String in SSIS Script Component

Tags: sql, ssis

How do I convert `BlobColumn` to `String` in `SSIS Script Component`.

**E.G:**

```
Source Column : OrganisationProviderID NVARCHAR(MAX)

Destination Column : OrganisationProviderID VARCHAR(20)
```

How can this be acheived in `SSIS Script Component`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the script component for this? Also, i'm not sure that a NVARCHAR(MAX) really qualifies as a BLOB column.

If you want to do it as part of a data flow task, on your Data Source, set the data access mode to 'SQL Command' then use the following command text:

```
select left(OrganisationProviderID,20) as OrganisationProviderID
from src
```

Then link this to your destination component.

Comment: I know this is a very old question/answer but I just wanted to note here for anyone else looking that yes indeed NVARCHAR(MAX) and VARCHAR(MAX) are both interpreted as an object named BlobColumn when using a DFT ScriptTask component. Not a choice, it's what the generator produces. Hence the need to convert a byte array into a string and in some cases back into a byte array in order to save it.

Answer (score 51):

Here is the function I use to convert BlobColumn to string in SSIS Script Components

```
string BlobColumnToString(BlobColumn blobColumn)
{
    if (blobColumn.IsNull)
        return string.Empty;

    var blobLength = Convert.ToInt32(blobColumn.Length);
    var blobData = blobColumn.GetBlobData(0, blobLength);
    var stringData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData);

    return stringData;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there any benefit of explicitly passing in the length to GetBlobData()?

Comment: @JasonHorner There isn't an overload for not passing the `Byte Array length` Thats probably why they did it this way

Comment: This solution worked for me when I changed var stringData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData); to var stringData = Encoding.Default.GetString(blobData);

Comment: var stringData = Encoding.Default.GetString(blobData);  >>  Used this based on comments to stop getting some chinese texts appearing on my web page.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this isn't BlobColumns' implementation of .ToString() ? Possibly with the ability to specify on the BlobColumn What encoding it should use?

Comment: Very important: include the needed library at the top of the script to avoid compiling errors.

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer and should really be marked as such. Thanks for answering the question with an actual answer; and not answering with a question to avoid the question being asked. I was completely clueless (and nervous) on how to handle this and now I know how.